# How can i make the interceptor run a function on error exept for one specific request?

Tags: axios, react-query

this is my interceptor:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
(response) => {
     if (error.response?.status === 403) {
        unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
            // to force react state changes outside of React components
            useSnackBarStore.getState().show({
                message: `${i18n.t('forbidden')}: ${error.toJSON().config.url}`,
                severity: 'error',
            })
        })
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
}
)
```

I want this behavior all the time except when I make this specific call or at least except every head call

```
export const companiesQueries = {
    headCompany: {
        name: 'headCompany',
        fn: async (companyId) => {
            return await axios.head(`/companies/${companyId}`)
        },
    },
```

Comment: You can create 2 separate axios instances with axios.create, one with interceptors and the other one without. And use them according to your needs for each case.

Refernce: https://axios-http.com/docs/instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by applying these changes to the api call:

```
const uninterceptedAxiosInstance = axios.create()

headCompany: {
    name: 'headCompany',
    fn: async (companyId) => {
        return await 
        uninterceptedAxiosInstance.head(`/companies/${companyId}`)
        },
    }
```